# Mouseover event not firing for Polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

On clicking a button, an AJAX request is made to the serverside which returns several polygon paths. These polygons are then drawn onto the map.

**Problem**: I added event handler for `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. However, they do not seem to be firing. The handler contains `console.log` which does not execute on mouseover. What may have caused this?

**JS Code**

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'main/get',
                function(json) {

                    for( var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                        decoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(json[i].encoded_path); 

                        var polyOptions = {
                                    strokeColor: "#4794b8", 
                                    strokeOpacity: 0.7, 
                                    strokeWeight: 1.5,
                                    fillColor: "#000",
                                    fillOpacity: 0.1,
                                    path: decoded_path, 
                                    clickable: false,
                                    map: map
                            }
                        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
                        array_polyline.push(polygon);

                        // Add Mouseover/Mouseout Listeners
                        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "mouseover", function(){ console.log('Mouseover'); this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0}); });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "mouseout", function(){ this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.1}); });

                    }

        });
});
```

Comment: when the code runs are you getting any errors ?

Comment: @ManseUK No errors when the code is run

Comment: And you can see the shapes on the map ? (sorry for the dumb basic questions - just making sure - as I can see nothing wrong with your code )

Comment: If you remove the `clickable: false` line does it work ? seems `clickable: false` may disable all mouse events ....

Comment: Awesome, the problem was `clickable: false` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either remove `clickable: false` or make it `clickable: true` (the default)

You dont have to bind to all events (ie click) but `clickable: false` disables all mouse events ...